# node-adal toekn expiry and caching

Tags: node.js, adal

Trying to use [node-adal](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs) library and have few questions.

1. Is there a function in the library that I could call to see if an access token has expired or not? I wanted to check if the current access token is valid or not, before refreshing it.
2. Currently I'm persisting the tokens to a azure storage, is there a way I could offload this to the library and let it deal with persisting the tokens to a table?
3. The C# version of adal library has a *AcquireTokenSilentAsync(String, ClientAssertion, UserIdentifier)* method that takes in an UserIdentifier. Is there an equivalent for the node version?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such method in the ADAL library to check whether the token is expired. However it provider an similar function `_refreshEntryIfNecessary` function to check and refresh the token. You can also decode the token which is base64 encoded and  extract the `exp` claim and compare with the date time. 
The expiration is represented as a **NumericDate**:

> A JSON numeric value representing the number of seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time, ignoring leap seconds. This is equivalent to the IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition [POSIX.1] definition "Seconds Since the Epoch", in which each day is accounted for by exactly 86400 seconds, other than that non-integer values can be represented. See RFC 3339 [RFC3339] for details regarding date/times in general and UTC in particular.

And here is the code using the `jsonwebtoken` for your reference:

```
function isTokenExpired(token) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(token);
    var isExpired = decoded.exp - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) < 0
    return isExpired;
}
console.log(isTokenExpired(token));
```

> Currently I'm persisting the tokens to a azure storage, is there a way I could offload this to the library and let it deal with persisting the tokens to a table?

What's the real issue block you? Based on my understanding, the business logic is implement by ourselves.

> The C# version of adal library has a AcquireTokenSilentAsync(String, ClientAssertion, UserIdentifier) method that takes in an UserIdentifier. Is there an equivalent for the node version?

There are several ways to acquire the token silently. For example, we can acquire the token from cache and refresh it if it was expired. We also can acquire the token using **Client Credential Flow** and **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow**. However, the ADAl for NodeJs doesn't provide corresponding method. You may submit the idea from the [Windows Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for Node.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs) on GitHub.